# What is on the contraband disc Thomas Anderson sells for $2000?

Tags: the-matrix

Near the start of The Matrix (1999), Thomas Anderson (a.k.a 'Neo'), sells computer disc (possibly a Sony Minidisk) for $2000 to a group of people who arrive, late, at his door. Anderson indicates that the disc can get them into a great deal of trouble and that they should under no circumstances reveal it came from him.

In the movie, no hint is given as to the content of this disc. Are any hints given in other media from The Matrix universe? What was Thomas Anderson selling?

Comment: Program to delete parking tickets. [It has been answered here.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12535/what-was-mr-anderson-neo-selling-on-discs-to-choi)